# What is maximum-edge in minimax algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am having a hard time understanding the minimax or maximin problem from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widest_path_problem)  wikipidea. The thing I can't understand is, what does the problem want? Does it want the shortest path from one node to another? If not this, than what? what is  minimum-weight or maximum weight? a clarification with example would be very much helpful.what I exactly want is that what is minimum of maximum weight? I don't understand relation between minimum and maximum.

Comment: What is called the "minimax algorithm" (an algorithm for 2 player game AI) is not the same as the subject of the linked Wikipedia page, which is the "minimax path problem". Which of them do you need to know about?

Comment: link for the game AI minimax https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax

Comment: It would be about the minimax algorithm that is finding minimum of maximum edge between two vertices. And @brian, I can't understand that link too...

Comment: @interjay The “minmax path problem” is *also* known as the “minmax algorithm” in computer science. That’s how it was introduced to us in the discrete maths postgrad course in University. Confusing, yes. But not OP’s fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation through an example: (derived from Wikipedia example)

The minimax path between Maldon and Feering is in red.

[image]

Here, the maximum between all the edges is 9.

```
max(8,9,7,8,9) = 9
```

There is no possible path where the maximum of all the edges is less than 9.

Note that this is not the shortest path, the shortest path would be the direct path between the two, with a cost of 10, but 10 > 9, so that would not be the minimax path.

Comment: So I guess an example problem would be: find me a path from Freering to Maldon accounting for the fact that I cannot bike more than 9 kilometers without a stop to a town for a sip of water (hence I cannot take the 10km direct route)?

Comment: @AndréCaron Well, sort of. The goal would be to *minimize* said distance. If you have an upper bound, you'd probably rather remove all edges with higher weight from the graph and run a regular shortest path algorithm.

Comment: and a MST always includes the lowest edge in its path, so answer is the path in the mst . :D thanks, nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is to find a path where the minimum edge on the path is as large is possible.

So, if you have a path P = e1, ..., ek, where ei is the edges weights, let f(P) be min(e1, ..., ek). You should find a path P* so that f(P*) is as high as possible.

Another possible interpretation of the problem: find a maximal weight W such that if you remove every edge with weight < W from the graph, there still will exist a path from source to target. In this case W = f(P*).